# Dependency not found in Nuxt when defining alias in nuxt.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, dependencies, nuxt.js

I'm getting this error when trying to import a file using a custom alias:

```
import api from 'api'

api in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/exercises.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

This is my nuxt.config.js:

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
const _api = process.env.API_MOCK === '1' ? 'apimock': 'api'

export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/router'
  ],
  alias: {
    'api': resolve(__dirname,  './helpers/' + _api)
  },
}
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
.
├── components
│   ├── drawer.vue
│   ├── popup-criar-treino.vue
│   ├── popup-treino.vue
│   └── toolbar.vue
├── helpers
│   ├── api
│   │   └── urls.js
│   └── apimock
│       ├── db_mock
│       │   └── db_mock.js
│       ├── mockadapter.js
│       └── urls.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── layouts
│   └── default.vue
├── nuxt.config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pages
│   ├── exercises.vue
│   ├── index.vue
│   ├── plans.vue
│   └── treinos.vue
└── router.js
```

I dont get what i'm missing here, i'm following the example in Nuxt docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-alias/

Comment: Are you sure `process.env.API_MOCK === '1' ? 'apimock': 'api'` is working as expected? Can you try having it hardcoded on the line `'api': resolve(__dirname,  './helpers/' + _api)` with `'api': resolve(__dirname,  './helpers/' + 'apimock')` rather?

Comment: Also, did you meant `import api from '~api/urls.js'` maybe? Or this one: ``import api from 'api/urls.js'``? This one? `import { api } from '~api/urls.js'`?

Comment: I tried with the hardcoded path and it didn't work as well. I was trying to ```import api from 'api'``` indeed, then i would call it as ```api.urls``` in my file, because i pretend to create another .js files in the api and apimock folders and use then the same way

Comment: I also tried importing as you suggested but it kept getting the same error

Comment: I also ran ```nuxt webpack resolve alias``` and it didn't show the api alias, just the default ones. But when i run only ```nuxt webpack```, it shows up in the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `axios` to `api.js` file

```
export default function ({ $axios, app }, inject) {
  const api = $axios.create({
    headers: {
      common: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization
      }
    }
  });
  inject('api', api)
}
```

Then add `api` to plugins then you can call it as `alias` in anywhere in app

```
  plugins: [    
    { src: '~/plugins/api.js' },
  ]
```

this.$api.get/post...

With your directory, you also can inject to NuxtApp like the way I suggest above;

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue here. OP have problem getting a working alias.